# Recorrer sub nodo JSON en vueJs

Tags: json, vue.js

```
"bloques": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "banner": "Banner_Doble_Megas_terminales2.jpg",
      "titulo": "Blindaje",
      "activo": 1,
      "contenidos": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "subseccion": 0,
          "icon": "fa fa-copy",
          "nombre": "Guía Rápida",
          "pdf": "pymes.pdf",
          "imagenes": "",
          "bloque_id": 1,
          "ruta": null,
          "activo": 1
        },
```

puedo reccorrer facilmente los bloques de la siguiente forma:

```
<tr v-for="(bloque, index) in bloques" :key="index">
```

Todo bien ahi, mi problema es cuando quiero acceder a `contenidos` intente usarlo:

```
<tr v-for="(bloque, index) in bloques.contenidos" :key="index">
```

entonces, como deberia recorrer uno despues de otro para que sigue la continuidad del array.

Comment: proba con bloque.contenidos, porque ya estas adentro del for anterior no?

Answer (score 1):

Bueno te comento una propuesta de solución.

Mientras que para los valores del primer nivel haces esto:

```
{{ bloque.banner }}
```

Y eso te da como resultado obtener:

```
Banner_Doble_Megas_terminales2.jpg
```

Para el siguiente nivel dentro de tus datos, deberías hacer lo siguiente

```
{{ bloque.contenidos[0]["pdf"] }}
```

Del anterior línea de código sacamos que:

- `bloque` corresponde a la clave que dentro del `v-for` me ayuda a iterar en los valores
- `contenidos es la clave` a través de la cual quiero llegar a sus valores
- `[0]` le indico que en el primer nivel de la clave  `contenidos` recordemos que es tratado como un `array` donde la primer posición se identifica por estar en el *índice 0*
- `["pdf"]` es la clave que dentro de `contenidos` que estoy intentando recuperar

Lo cual te va a devolver en mi HTML lo siguiente:

```
pymes.pdf
```

> Aclaración como todos los datos, tanto los del primer nivel como los
>   del segundo forman parte de una misma clave; entonces la estructura de
>   tu declaración en el HTML a través de un `v-for` debe ser así *(una
>   estructura anidada)* es decir una secundaria dentro de una princial;
>   donde la secundaria depende de la variable de la primera

```
<div id="app">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="bloque in bloques">
         El id es: {{ bloque.id }}
         <p>el documento es: {{ bloque.contenidos[0]["pdf"] }}</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Finalmente el resultado del código completo debería ser este:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="app">
        <ul>
          <li v-for="bloque in bloques">
             El id es: {{ bloque.id }}
             <p>el documento es: {{ bloque.contenidos[0]["pdf"] }}</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
    <script>
      let app = new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data:{
          bloques: [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "banner": "Banner_Doble_Megas_terminales2.jpg",
          "titulo": "Blindaje",
          "activo": 1,
          "contenidos": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "subseccion": 0,
              "icon": "fa fa-copy",
              "nombre": "Guía Rápida",
              "pdf": "pymes.pdf",
              "imagenes": "",
              "bloque_id": 1,
              "ruta": null,
              "activo": 1
            }]
        }
    ]
        }
      })
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: y porque no un v-for dentro de un v-for?

Comment: No tuve tiempo de probar más, es la primera respuesta que se me ocurrió, no puedo agregar más pues estoy desde mi cel @gbianchi

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta a tu pregunta es:

```
<tr v-for="(bloque, index) in bloques" :key="index">
  {{ index }}: {{ bloque.id }}
  ...
  ...
  <span>Contenidos:</span>
  <ul>
    <tr v-if="bloque.contenidos.length > 0" v-for="(val, i) in bloque.contenidos" :key="i">
    Contenido {{ i }}:
    <template v-for="(dato, nombre) in val" :key="nombre">
      {{ nombre }}: {{ dato }}
    </template>
    ...
  </ul>
```

Así te imprimiría toda tu data.